why getting error using ffmpeg Could find no file with path 'frame_%4.bmp' and index in the range 0-4?
the command line
D:\Output1>ffmpeg -f image2 -framerate 1 -i frame_%4.bmp -loop 0 d:\video.gif
[image2 @ 000001f981d10380] Could find no file with path 'frame_%4.bmp' and index in the range 0-4 [in#0 @ 000001f981d0f040] Error opening input: No such file or directory Error opening input file frame_%4.bmp. Error opening input files: No such file or directory
screenshot image showing the files names on my hard disk.


try ffmpeg -start_number 4528 -f image2 -framerate 1 -i frame_%04d.bmp out.gif

@БаярГончикжапов why do i need the -start_number 4528 part ?  if for example i don't know the file name ? for example i have 3000 bitmap files with different names some with 4 digits some with 2 digits some with 7 digits.  and i want to put them all in animated gif.  is there a way to do it automatically ?  you comment command line is working but i wonder if there something more generic.

if libavformat was compiled with globbing support, it can be used with glob() option → ffmpeg -framerate 1 -pattern_type glob -i "*.bmp" out.gif. mostly in nix. under windows you can rename input files to desired sequence

I forgot about imagemagick → magick -delay 100 -loop 0 -dispose previous *.bmp out.gif
